# implementation of class member arrays: invalid type for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm fairly new to C++, and I have a project in which I need to organize a seating chart for a concert using a class. Trouble is, I am getting the error message "error: invalid types ‘type[int]’ for array subscript" throughout a lot of my implementation code, even though I am reasonably certain that my array declarations in the class are legal and are implemented correctly.

Here is the header code containing the class:

```
#ifndef HALL_H
#define HALL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const double     PRICE_HI = 200.0;
    const int MIN_HI_SEAT = 5;
    const int MAX_HI_SEAT = 16;
    const char MAX_HI_ROW = 'H';
const double     PRICE_LO = 150.0;
const char       MAX_ROWS = 'N';
const int        NUM_ROWS = 14;
const int       NUM_SEATS = 20;
const int         MAX_RES = 12;
const double     DISCOUNT = 0.9;
const string        BLANK = "---";
const int        NUM_DAYS = 7;

class Hall {
    public:
        string  name[NUM_ROWS][NUM_SEATS];

        Hall         ();
        bool request (string, int, string, int);
        bool cancel  (string);
        void print   ();

    private:    
        char     row[NUM_ROWS];
        int     seat[NUM_SEATS];
        bool      hi[NUM_ROWS][NUM_SEATS];
        double price[NUM_ROWS][NUM_SEATS];

        bool process  (string, int, string, int);
        void revenue  ();
        string enough (int, string, bool);
        bool count    (int, bool);
        void make     (string, int, string, int, bool, string);
        void assign   (string, int, int, int, int, bool, bool, string);
        void leftover (string, int, int);
        void output   (string, int, int, int);
};

#endif
```

Here is the constructor in the implementation, as an example of code getting the error message:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hall.h"
using namespace std;

    Hall::Hall()
{   
    char row = 'A';
    int seat = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SEATS; j++) {
        row[i]      = row;
        seat[j]     = seat;
        name[i][j]  = BLANK;
        price[i][j] = 0;
        if (row[i]  <= MAX_HI_ROW  &&
            seat[j] >= MIN_HI_SEAT &&
            seat[j] <= MAX_HI_SEAT) {
            hi[i][j] = true;
        } else {
            hi[i][j] = false;
        }
        seat++;
    }
    seat = 1;
    row++;
    }
}
```

And here are the error messages for the constructor:

```
hall.cpp: In constructor ‘Hall::Hall()’:                                                                                         
hall.cpp:11: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
hall.cpp:12: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hall.cpp:15: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
hall.cpp:16: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
hall.cpp:17: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
```

I've been baffled by this for a while now, and appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Try renaming local variables in constructor. You have class data members arrays `row` and `seat` which are shadowed by local non-array declarations `row` and `seat` in constructor. Or specify class member access using `this->row`, `this->seat`.

Answer (score 2):

These local variables:

```
char row = 'A';
int seat = 1;
```

hide the members with the same names. Either choose different names, or access the members as `this->row` and `this->seat`.

Comment: Thanks! Nothing like comp sci to make me feel like an utter fool.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are duplicated, local row variables covers your row array variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is very a bad idea that you named local variables of the constructor the same way as data members of the class. So what do these statements mean?

```
row[i]      = row;
seat[j]     = seat;
```

At least it would be better to write

```
this->row[i]      = row;
this->seat[j]     = seat;
```

or

```
Hall::row[i]      = row;
Hall::seat[j]     = seat;
```